# upload kml map to my android app

Tags: android, kml

i tried to find how i could load kml file and I found that I can use:

```
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/ 
    documentation/KML_Samples.kml"); 
    mapIntent.setData(uri1); 
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mapIntent, "Sample"));
```

is there any other way such that i can upload the kml file locally from my pc rather than having to upload it to a website, then use it..as I am developing an applications and usually other users wont be able to access the kml of they dont have the username and password for the link

please if anyone can help, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an account in googlecode and upload the kml file, so it'll be on the internet and everybody can see it

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=http://miruta.googlecode.com/files/miruta.kml");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
mapIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mapIntent, "Sample Map")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

KML map in android is now officially available on [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml).

You can easily load KML file from local resource folder or from inputstreams into your android app as below.

From local resource:-

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(map, R.raw.geojson_file, context);
```

From InputStreams:-

```
InputStream inputStream = // InputStream containing KML data
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(map, inputStream, context);
```